# Inserting a nested object in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have this document saved in my mongo collection called `exam`

```
// meteor:PRIMARY> db.exam.find()
{
    "_id" : "RLvWTcsrbRXJeTqdB",
    "examschoolid" : "5FF2JRddZdtTHuwkx",
    "examsubjects" : [
        {
            "subject" : "Z4eLrwGwqG4pw4HKX"
        },
        {
            "subject" : "fFcWby8ArpboizcT9"
        }
    ],
    "examay" : "NrsP4srFGfkc5cJkz",
    "examterm" : "5A5dNTgAkdRr5j53j",
    "examclass" : "gYF2wE4wBCRy9a3ZC",
    "examname" : "First",
    "examdate" : ISODate("2016-05-07T22:41:00Z"),
    "examresultsstatus" : "notreleased"
}
```

I am trying to select data from this document and saving it into another using this code.The aim is to have the `examsubjects` value in the document above to be the key in the document i am inserting into.

```
'click .reactive-table tr': function() {
    Session.set('selectedPersonId', this._id);
    var cursor = Exam.find({ _id:
            Session.get("selectedPersonId")}).fetch();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc){
        for (i = 0; i < doc.examsubjects.length; i++) {
            for (var prop in doc.examsubjects[i]) {
                console.log("obj." + prop + " = " + doc.examsubjects[i][prop]);
                var subj = doc.examsubjects[i][prop];
                Told.insert({
                    examschoolid:"sms",
                    examname:doc.examname,
                    examsubjects: [{subj : "0"}],
                    examay:doc.examay,
                    examterm:doc.examterm,
                    examclass:doc.examclass,
                    examdate:doc.examdate
                });
            }
        }
    });
},
```

When the code runs,the variable `subj` that holds the subjects value just inserts subj not knowing its a variable like this

```
{
    "_id" : "5yjwFanBAupgu9GHq",
    "examschoolid" : "sms",
    "examname" : "First",
    "examsubjects" : [
        {
            "subj" : "0"
        }
    ],
    "examay" : "NrsP4srFGfkc5cJkz",
    "examterm" : "5A5dNTgAkdRr5j53j",
    "examclass" : "gYF2wE4wBCRy9a3ZC",
    "examdate" : ISODate("2016-05-07T22:41:00Z")
}
```

Why is the variable not being seen as a variable?.

Edit

```
'click .reactive-table tr': function() {
    Session.set('selectedPersonId', this._id);
    var cursor = Exam.find({ _id: Session.get("selectedPersonId")}).fetch();
    cursor.forEach(function(doc){

        var sq = function(){
            for (i = 0; i < doc.examsubjects.length; i++) {
                for (var prop in doc.examsubjects[i]) {
                    const subj = doc.examsubjects[i][prop];
                    let subject = {};
                    subject[subj] = "0";
                    return [subject];

                }
            }
        }
        console.log(sq());
        Told.insert({
            examschoolid:"sms",
            examname:doc.examname,
            examsubjects: sq(),
            examay:doc.examay,
            examterm:doc.examterm,
            examclass:doc.examclass,
            examdate:doc.examdate
        });

    });
    //Uncaught TypeError: cursor.count is not a function
},
```

The updated code almost works,but only inserts 1 record.

Comment: How many documents do you want created? One for each `doc.examsubjects` object? In addition, I would suggest learning the basics of JavaScript before jumping to the "deeper water" of Meteor.

Comment: I want the data in this format `"examsubjects" : [
        {
            "Z4eLrwGwqG4pw4HKX" : "0",
            "fFcWby8ArpboizcT9" : "0"
        }
        ]` when i do the insert.

Comment: Will the `examsubjects` have any properties other than `subject`?

Comment: Nevermind,am working on it.

Answer (score 2):

That's how JSON works, it takes keys literally. Fix it by using ES6 brackets notation:

```
examsubjects: [{
  [subj] : "0"
}],
```

Comment: Nice. Assuming the OP is using ES2015, I would go for this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it is treated as a key in a literal object.

If you want to have `subj`'s value as your key, you will need to use the bracket notation, creating the object beforehand:

```
const subj = doc.examsubjects[i][prop];
let subject = {};
subject[subj] = "0";

Told.insert({
    examschoolid:"sms",
    examname:doc.examname,
    examsubjects: [subject],
    ...
});
```

Comment: This code works but like in my very first object all subjects should go under  exam subjects `"examsubjects" : [
        {
            "subject" : "Z4eLrwGwqG4pw4HKX"
        },
        {
            "subject" : "fFcWby8ArpboizcT9"
        }
    ],`  The code creates two documents instead of two records under `examsubjects`

Comment: So perform the insert after the loop. Right now you are inserting in the loop itself, and each `insert` creates a separate object. Add them to an array (You can probably use `Array.map()`) and insert once.

Comment: Not the way you did it and I would not recommend this approach anyway. It is pretty straightforward to create the array. Also not that you did not declare `i` anywhere.